# Label text as equation

Tags: labels, text

I want to label a piece of text as a mathematical equation to refer to below. Thanks for everyone's guidance.
[image]

Comment: Simply use `\begin{equation} 36 - 12 = 24 \label{somelabel} \end{equation}`, and later use `\ref{somelabel}`.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you want the entire paragraph below the first displayed equation to be treated as "equation (2)". If this assumption is correct, you may achieve your formatting objective by appending the instruction

```
\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:second}(\theequation)
```

to the paragraph in question. If you need to do this several times, it's probably a good idea to create a shortcut macro, say,

```
\newcommand\appendeqnum[1]{%
    \hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}(\theequation)}
```

The first (and only) argument of `\appendeqnum` is the label you wish to assign to this "equation".

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for filler text
\newcommand\appendeqnum[1]{%
    \hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{equation} \label{eq:first}
36-12=24
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-2]\appendeqnum{eq:second}

\lipsum[3][1-2]

A cross-reference to equation (\ref{eq:second}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to take into account the fact that the text may end too far to the right for an equation number to fit, so this will go to the beginning of the next line.  (I know the code for the workaround has appeared in this forum, but I can't find it.)  Use the technique that is used in `amsthm` to set the qed box at the end of a proof.